# how to do Same Position of One Div which is dynamically occur in a table of two rows & 4 tds?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to do same position one div which occur in my page dynamically at different position.

I have one table of two rows containing two td's in each & that td I have Embed button. On click on that Embed button I show One div containing site list & its occur dynamically for four buttons.

Here is a html code:

```
    <table class="allListTbl" id="appListTbl">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center">
            <marquee behavior="alternate" width="55%">
            <img src="static/images/yolaLogo70x70.jpg" alt="yola_logo" style="width:35px; height:35px; margin-left:2%;" id="yolaLogo"/>
            <img src="static/images/weeblyLogo70x70.jpg" alt="webly_logo" style="width:35px; height:35px;  margin-left:2%;" id="weblyLogo"/>
            <img src="static/images/godaddyLogo70x70.jpg" alt="godaddy_logo" style="width:35px; height:35px; margin-left:2%;" id="godaddyLogo"/>
            <img src="static/images/moonfruitLogo70x70.jpg" alt="moomfruit_logo" style="width:35px; height:35px;  margin-left:2%;" id="moomfruitLogo"/>
            <img src="static/images/htmlLogo70x70.png" alt="customBuild"  style="width:35px; height:35px;  margin-left:2%;" id="customBuild"/>
            <img src="static/images/jimdoLogo70x70.jpg" alt="jimdoLogo"  style="width:35px; height:35px; margin-left:2%;" id="jimdoLogo"/>
            <img src="static/images/squarespaceLogo70x70.jpg" alt="squareSpaceLogo"  style="width:35px; height:35px; margin-right:1px;" id="squareSpaceLogo"/>
            </marquee>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table class="mediaFeedTbl" id="mediaFeedTbl">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <img src="static/images/MediaFeedNewLogo.png" alt="mediafeedLogo" style="width:60px; height:60px;" id="mediaFeedLogo"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="AppNameOne">Media Feed</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="justify" valign="top">
                        <p id="appDescrptnOne">
                        Media Feeds or blogs or press coverages are essential to boost your credibility and reputation in the market. Ability to effectively and easily display them on your web site                                                that can impress your customer is essential.
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="demoBtn"  id="demoBtnOne" value="Demo"/>
                    </td>
                    <td id="mickey">
                        <input type="button" class="embedBtn"  id="mediaFeedEmbed" value="Embed"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="propertyTbl" id="propertyTbl">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <img src="static/images/propertyUpload_logo.png" alt="propertyUploadLogo" style="width:60px; height:60px;" id="uploadPropertyLogo"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="AppNameTwo">Upload Property</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="justify" valign="top">
                        <p id="appDescrptnTwo">
                        With the Upload Property app your website visitors will be empowered to easily upload their property listings to you, allowing you to expand your real estate business with                                                    ease.
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="demoBtn"  id="demoBtnTwo" value="Demo"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="embedBtn"  id="uploadPropertyEmbed" value="Embed"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table class="tblrsrvtnTbl" id="tblrsrvtnTbl">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <img src="static/images/logo7_style1.png" alt="tblresrvtnLogo" style="width:60px; height:60px;" id="tblResrvtnLogo"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <p><span id="AppNameThr">Restaurant Booking</span></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="justify" valign="top">
                        <p id="appDescrptnThr">
                        SCUBE offers one of the easiest and most flexible ways for restaurants to take complete control over their reservations booking process. Guests can book a table in a cost                                                effective and effortless way. Restaurant Booking by SCUBE provides functionality to easily manage daily rush hours and group bookings and has rich reporting features to make                                                sure that management is always in the know.
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="demoBtn"  id="demoBtnThr" value="Demo"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="embedBtn"  id="restaurantBookingEmbed" value="Embed"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <table class="salonTbl" id="salonTbl">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <img src="static/images/Spa_Salon_logo.png" alt="SpaSalonLogo" style="width:60px; height:60px;" id="spaSalonLogo"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="AppNameFour">Salon Appointment</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="justify" valign="top">
                        <p id="appDescrptnFour">
                        SCUBE offers one of the easiest and most flexible ways for Salons to take complete control over their services. Interested clients can schedule an appointment in a cost                                                                  effective and effortless way.
                        Grow your business by managing your services and clients effectively.
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="demoBtn"  id="demoBtnFour" value="Demo"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="embedBtn"  id="saloonAppEmbed" value="Embed"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/e4n6rxba/)?

Answer (score 0):

You looking something like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/m791hfbo/1/ or http://fiddle.jshell.net/8f69y89x/?